# Any free service to redirect a port to some address?

Tags: centos, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a server where I would need to connect, but I can't do it on the standard method due to the network settings, so I was guessing if it exists some service or daemon that could bind the SSH port to some address like for example `server1.theservice.com` or something in that way. Like [localtunnel](http://progrium.com/localtunnel/) but for SSH. It'd be for a CentOS server, thanks!

Comment: . . . are you attempting to subvert access restrictions at someone's site?

Comment: mmm no, it's my server, I want someone to access my server via SSH :/

Comment: If it's your server - what 'network settings' are blocking them from accessing SSH?  If you tell us that - we can work out the best way to work around them or resolve them.

Comment: Well, the server is mine, but it's on my company, that means there's a firewall which I don't manage, so I can't ask for the admin to open me the port

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the server, how about an SSH Reversed connection? http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually is the only answer / comment that was useful ;)